# A novel with an intro scene mentioning "non-shivering thermogenesis"

Tags: story-identification, novel

Around 2000 I read in English the first couple of pages of a novel and never had the chance to find it again. I don't think it was very new by then; I'd guess 90's.

I think someone was in bed, possibly in a hospital, unconscious and recovering from something. The narrator (a doctor tending to the patient?) is hoping the patient pulls through, but seems dubious; also seems in awe because of "non-shivering thermogenesis", as if it was something uncommon/unexpected. Not sure they mention brown fat (the real-world mechanism for that thermogenesis).

Comment: @fez by the time I read that intro, NST was understood to not be possible in adult humans. So yes, it was science fiction. Only, around 2010 it was discovered that it is possible after all. Mentioning this because I don't see why the rush to assume that it's not science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @hmijailmournsresignees - please don't be turned off by the question about whether it is SF/Fantasy.  It is not a 'rush to assume'; it is just a question to check whether the question is posted to the right site; people make mistakes.  It was simply not clear in the question that this story had any SF/Fantasy elements.  People frequently post, mistakenly, on the wrong site and need help finding the right place.

Comment: @Basya three close votes for 'not about Sf&F' seems more like a rush to assume rather than a check for clarity.

Comment: I see.  How does one see what the close votes are?  I thought the user was responding to comments questioning whether it was SF/F....

Comment: @hmijailmournsresignees - without knowing exactly what 'non-shivering thermogenesis' is the question didn't immediately appear to be SFF-nal. I should have waited a little more for you to come back with more info. Close vote retracted and I'm glad to see you've found your story!

Comment: @Basya if you click on vote to close yourself, you can trace through the options other close voters have chosen before having to commit to a vote.

Comment: @Jontia - I'm not there yet; I can't vote to close for another 984 reputation....I guess that's why I never have seen this....

Comment: @Basya thanks for the encouragement. Yes, I was answering to such comments; they're no longer there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's just possible you are thinking of the introduction to part five of [Blue Mars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77504.Blue_Mars) by Kim Stanley Robinson. It isn't in the opening pages, though it is an introduction to a part of the book.

> An old man sitting at sickbed. Hospital rooms are all the same. Clean, white, cool, humming, fluorescent. On the sickbed lies a man, tall, dark-skinned, thick black eyebrows. Sleeping fitfully. The old man is hunched at his head. One finger touches the skull behind the ear. Under his breath the old man is muttering. “If it’s an allergic response, then your own immune system has to be convinced that the allergen isn’t really a problem. They haven’t identified an allergen. Pulmonary edema is usually high-altitude sickness, but maybe the mix of gases caused it, or maybe it was low-altitude sickness. You need to get water out of your lungs. They’ve done pretty well with that. The fever and chills might be amenable to biofeedback. A really high fever is dangerous, you must remember that. I remember the time you came into the baths after falling into the lake. You were blue. Jackie jumped right in— no, maybe she stopped to watch. You held Hiroko and me by the arms, and we all saw you warm up. **Nonshivering thermogenesis**, everyone does it, but you did it voluntarily, and very powerfully as well. I’ve never seen anything like it. I still don’t know how you did it. You were a wonderful boy. People can shiver at will if they want, so maybe it’s like that, only inside. It doesn’t really matter, you don’t need to know how, you just need to do it. If you can do it in the other direction. Bring your temperature down. Give it a try. Give it a try. You were such a wonderful boy.”

The person in the sickbed is *Nirgal*, who is ill because he has returned to Earth only to be felled by allergies.

I suppose it's possible you might have found part five of the book published separately as an extract, or as a serialisation.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you lots!

Comment: The episode that this character is recalling actually occurred very early on in the previous novel *Green Mars*, so that's another possibility for what you might be remembering.

Comment: There's a Part 5! . . . hang on . . . there's a part 4?!?!?!?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Part 5 of the individual book *Blue Mars*; **not** book #5 in the *Mars* trilogy, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: Ah . . . ok . . . sorry for the confusion, I'll just be over here having a little cry so